# pattern match failing while finding a file

Tags: python

I am trying to find  a file `*tech.so` in a given path as below but somehow the `fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern)` is failing,can anyone suggest how to fix this?

```
import os, fnmatch

path = "\\\\location1\\build1\\obj\\vendor\\qcom\\opensource\\tech"

def find(pattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            #print name
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result

result  = find('*.tech.so', path)
print result//prints empty string
```

Comment: remove \ in '*.tech\.so' - it is not regex. - [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html)

Comment: still doesn't match

Comment: Your path has backslashes, which is wrong except on Windows (and forward slashes work on Windows, just not from the command line).  Are you sure os.walk is finding any matches?

Comment: print name and see what you get.

Comment: @cco and furas - it is printing the names but failing `if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):`

Comment: the exact file name is `caq_cdl3_tech.so` ,i can see this gets printed as part of name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your match pattern is `*.tech.so`, but the name you're looking for is `caq_cdl3_tech.so`

fnmatch patterns aren't the same as a regex, so `.` only matches a literal `.`, not 'any single character' as it would in a regex.

using `*tech.so` or `*_tech.so` as the pattern should work.

Comment: also the output is print in a list format like `['\\\\location1\\build1\\obj\\vendor\\qcom\\opensource\\tech\\caq_cdl3_tech.so']` ,how to get it to a windows supported accessible path

Comment: Do you mean that this is what you get from `print result` after changing the pattern?

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you mean - that looks like (the `repr` of) a perfectly good UNC path.  try printing `result[0]` to see what I mean.